# Estimate parameters in partially observed dynamic system?

Tags: python, r, ode

Just wondering if anybody knows whether there are (R/Python) libraries to estimate parameters in partially observed dynamical systems (or systems of ODEs)?

For example, let `t` be time and `theta` be a set of parameters,

```
dsdt = f(s, r, t|theta)
drdt = g(s, r, t|theta)
dndt = dsdt + drdt
```

where `dndt` are observed and `dsdt, drdt` are NOT observed. However we do know the initial values of `dsdt` and `drdt`.

Given a set of `theta`, `deSolve` in `R` can solve the ODEs, but I'm stucked in parameter estimation of `theta`.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Any procedure that does non-linear fitting or non-linear minimization can be used. There should be a variety in both R and python (scipy.optimize). Then there are specialized packages such as python-gekko.

Comment: I agree with Lutz Lehmann and want to add that R has also several such packages: e.g. package **FME**. A documentation is found in the following JSS paper https://do.org/10.18637/jss.v033.i03 and in the vignettes of the package.

Comment: Many thanks both - will try them out. Much appreciated!